# NSKeyedArchiver nil values in Dictcionary

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver

I am trying to convert a Swift Dictionary to data using NSKeyedArchiver. My question is if the dictionary has some of the key values as nil, how is NSKeyedArchiver supposed to handle it? Does it convert nil object to something like NSNull, or will it crash?

Answer (score 1):

If any of them is `nil` or both it won't crash

```
let key:String! = nil
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:[key:""])
print(data) // 289 bytes
let res = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data)
print(res) // Optional({"<null>" = "";})
```

Comment: Well my question was other way, where value is nil but key is not. In that case, what is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you turn around what wrote @Sh_Khan, you'll have your answer:

```
let key : String? = nil
let data = try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: ["test":key], requiringSecureCoding: false)
print(data) // 293 bytes
let res = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data)
print(res) // Optional({ test = "<null>"; })
```

It transforms `nil` values to  `"<null>"` strings.